# Highlighting tool overlap with multiple lines in Mac Preview on Yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, preview.app

I updated to Yosemite on my MacBook Pro. When I try to highlight two lines of text on Preview, the highlight overlaps, which looks really horrible. Is there a way to control the height (size) of the highlighting tool?

See Image below.

[image]

Comment: This is driving me crazy in OS X El Capitan as well(Preview v 8.1).

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd suggest, that there are unwanted interactions with a non-apple app.

Did You look at the error- logfiles  on the console?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shortcoming and the workaround I use is to export your pdf as a ps(postscript) file. You can do this by printing a document and selecting to save the document as a postscript in the print dialog box. Once you do that, you can open the ps file and start highlighting and it doesn't overlap. The workaround is a pain but that is the only workaround for now.

I've also heard that you can also download Preview 7.0(mavericks) on Yosemite, and use that, but I haven't tried it myself.